# Update a table using another table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE Products 
SET TotalQuantity = (CASE WHEN  P.DateOfLastUpdate < PurchaseDate 
THEN (SUM(P.TotalQuantity) + SUM(M.Quantity)) 
ELSE P.TotalQuantity END) 
FROM Products AS P ,Products_Purchased as M 
WHERE P.ProductName = M.ProductName;
```

I want to update table Products with respect to the another table Products_Purchased. If I add new item to Products_Purchased, it must be entered in table Products too and also should update TotalQuantity field of table 
Products. Whats wrong in this query?

I got error message:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Products AS P ,Products_Sold as S WHERE P.ProductName = S.ProductName' at line 1

Can anybody help me to sort out this one..?

Comment: Do you get an error message? Does the query give you the wrong answer? There's not enough information here at the moment to help.

Comment: i got error message :ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Products AS P ,Products_Sold as S WHERE P.ProductName = S.ProductName' at line 1

Comment: @No'amNewman there are two tables Products and Products_Purchased. If i enter new Product entry in Products_Purchased then information (like TotalQuantity )of same Product should be updated in table Products also.Each entry of Products in table "Products" must be single.It should not repeat the same Productname in table "Products".In Products_Purchased table ,different products info like dateofpurchased ,quantity can be inserted.

Comment: Two observations: (1) The database isn't designed very well - inventory should only be recorded in one place. If the 'products_purchased' table contains the actual movements (date and amount sold), then there shouldn't be a 'totalquantity' field in the 'products' table. (2) According to the SQL standard, an 'update' statement can't have a join in it. You may have to use a subquery, but the case statement makes this complicated.

Comment: As written, the query will try to update every single part in the 'products' table, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved your problem.Just follow what I did..

I created two tables

```
 create table products(product_name text,total_quantity int,date_of_lastupdate date);

 create table products_purchased(product_name text,quantity int,date_of_purchase date);

  insert into products values('food',10,'2013-5-6'),('dress',20,'2012-4-7');

  insert into products_purchased('food',15,'2012-2-1'),('dress',12,'2013-6-8');
```

Now I tried to update in the same condition which you were trying using the following code and it worked perfectly.

Just go through the code,you'll understand what I did and it'll solve your problem..

update products as a,products_purchased as b set a.total_quantity=

case

when a.date_of_lastupdate

then (select * from (select   sum(products.total_quantity)+sum(products_purchased.quantity) from products natural join     products_purchased)as c)

else a.total_quantity

end

where a.productname=b.productname ;

Comment: thanks Abhik Dey, i will try this one.. i have created these two tables as u mentioned. what i need is if i update table Products_Purchased by adding new item in it, it must be inserted into table Products also. i shouldn't insert data directly to Products.

Comment: Yes I understood what you need,you'll be absolutely able to fulfil your need through this code which I gave,whenever you'll update anything in your products_purchased table,the products table will be automatically updated through the above code

Comment: but it doesn't add new item entry into table Products which is only available in Products_Purchased table.

Comment: this query doesn't check for dateoflastupdate and purchasedate condition. and even doen't update the TotalQuantity field.. Please can u give me any solution..

Comment: it gives TotalQuantity as NULL

Answer (score 0):

**think an UPDATE FROM with a JOIN will help:**

```
UPDATE
    Sales_Import
SET
    Sales_Import.AccountNumber = RAN.AccountNumber
FROM
    Sales_Import SI
INNER JOIN
    RetrieveAccountNumber RAN
ON 
    SI.LeadID = RAN.LeadID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE Products 
SET TotalQuantity = 
(SELECT CASE WHEN  P.DateOfLastUpdate < PurchaseDate 
THEN (SUM(P.TotalQuantity) + SUM(M.Quantity)) 
ELSE P.TotalQuantity END
FROM Products AS P ,Products_Purchased as M 
WHERE P.ProductName = M.ProductName
AND P.ProductName = :p1)
WHERE ProductName = :p1
```

:p1 is a parameter which holds the name of the part to be updated.

Comment: i don't understand what should be :p1 in my query... can u please explain this.?

Comment: p1 is a parameter, which in this case would be the product number which you want to update. If you want to update *all* the products in one query, then remove the last two lines (but don't forget the closing bracket!).